# Htaccess - rewriting subfolder names as GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can somebody please tell me the exact code to convert #1 to #2? I'm new to `.htaccess` and I am having trouble with this.

1. `http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/`
2. `http://www.domain.com/folder.php?param1=subfolder1&param2=subfolder2&param3=subfolder3`

I want the URL in the address bar to keep being #1 so that is what the user sees. Meanwhile, the server treats the URL as page #2 so I can use GET variables in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(folder)/(subfolder1)/subfolder2/subfolder3/?$ /$1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```